# Insert without values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**Introduction**
I have a database named *User*, with two tables inside: `userinfo` and `usermeta`.
(usermeta is expected to be extented) For now `usermeta` has two columns user_meta_id which should match a `user_id` (both primary keys) and `user_info` (with a standard value of NULL). In the sign up part I add all needed values to the `userinfo` table (passwords etc.) What I want is to just like triggering the primary key `user_meta_id` to set a id in usermeta, and not yet set a user_info value.
So I tried "INSERT INTO usermeta" but obviously this doesn't work.

My other query to add information in the userinfo table is

```
INSERT INTO userinfo (user_name, user_email, user_password, user_sname) 
       VALUES ('$fname','$email','$encPassword','$sname')
```

**Question**
How can I trigger `user_meta_id` to set an id the same as `user_id` (both queries are running almost at the same time, thought: "So they set the same id of the user")

I hope you understand my question, if you have any question about my question or the "background" feel free to ask :D

**Edit**
User php code + sql query:

```
$registerQuery = "INSERT INTO userinfo (user_name, user_email, user_password, user_sname)
            VALUES ('$fname','$email','$encPassword','$sname')";
            $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
```

To add the foreign key sql:

```
ALTER TABLE usermeta ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_meta_id) REFERENCES userinfo.user_id
```

Comment: Try to get the last inserted record `id`. after the first query.

Comment: Okee, which means my user_meta_id sould be an auto increment any more?

Comment: It should be an foreign key. But you should keep an id with autoincrement also. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using

PDO:

```
$last_affected_id = $yourPdoConnectObject->lastInsertId();
```

http://php.net/manual/tr/pdo.lastinsertid.php

mysqli:

```
$last_affected_id = mysqli_insert_id($connection);
```

or

```
$last_affected_id = $connection->insert_id;
```

http://php.net/manual/tr/mysqli.insert-id.php

Also If you connect two tables with a key, one of them should be primary key and another should be foreign key

Foreign key:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DiVGuOXpl34

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FCtGbrou5DM

Comment: Hi hakkikonu, thanks for your answer. I am taking a look at it, I am still relative new to sql so please give me a minute to understand what is happening

Comment: I added 2 extra youtube video

Comment: I added the foreign key, link user_meta_id -> user_id (can't really describe it), and also added the code $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn). Well I got no errors, But I can't see the user_id added in the column user_meta_id.

Comment: Okey done, If somehting is unclear or you need more code, just ask ;)

Comment: on your php code, you just assigned your SQL query to $registerQuery variable. You should execute this query, after you should get last id

Comment: Ow oke got it, and now tho wrap things up I need to do the following query right? "INSERT INTO usermeta (user_meta_id) VALUES ('$last_id')"

Comment: please, first learn how to insert data into MYSQL http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: Hu what? I know how to insert data into mysql from php only thing is do I use the right query for sql, but well I will just do it. Just was wondering if I was about to use the right query